# Why is my '05 Ford Crown Vic smoking now that I've added Lucas Stop Leak engine oil?

Tags: engine, ford, smoke, crown-victoria

I put a whole bottle of Lucas Stop Leak oil in my `'05 Ford Crown Vic` followed by 5 qts of oil.

Now, **it's smoking out of the tailpipes**.  It is white smoke that looks like a fire being put out. I've shut the car off and am sitting on the side of the road.  I'm afraid to start it back up.

Why could it be smoking?

Comment: Were you doing an oil change in the car? Why did you add 5 quarts of oil?

Comment: No I was just adding oil because it was almost empty from the leak

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Where is it smoking from, the tail pipe?

Comment: I would bet if you were 5 quarts low, you have fried the oil control rings and smoke is inevitable out the tail pipe. Drive it home, keeping oil in it all the way. Once there, the engine will need a rebuild.

Comment: The vehicle won't catch fire. The engine will need to be rebuilt or replaced because it is more than likely ruined for whatever reason. The Barrs Stop Leak won't fix your issues.

Comment: check the pcv line for oil. when you added the 5 quarts including the 1 qt(?) stop leak was the crankcase completely empty? how's the oil level now?

Comment: It is possible that you've got too much oil in it now. As @Ben suggested, the first thing to do is to check your oil level.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the oil level when cold and on a flat surface?

Checking the oil when at normal operating temps will give you an inaccurate reading. The oil needs to be in the pan to check.

If you checked while it was hot and then added too much, you most likely blew the engine.